# The difference between 'bestimmt' and 'besondere' in German

Tags: meaning, adjective, synonym

I am a little bit confused about the usage of these synonyms. Can you show some examples, please,  where I can see the difference of these two adjectives meaning 'special'?

Edit: 
I've seen that 'bestimmt' is translated 'special' in this [website](https://quizlet.com/6151425/100-top-german-adjectives-flash-cards/)
[image].

Based on some comments, I think there is misspelling on the website, please let me know if it is true.

Comment: Could you provide an example text? I would not translate _bestimmt_ with 'special' in English. It can be used as a synonym for the german word _speziell_ but to me the best English translation for that would be _particular_. I am not a native English speaker though.

Comment: Thanks @BerndKonfuzius. I am learning online with this website https://quizlet.com/6151425/100-top-german-adjectives-flash-cards/. Here if you go down the translation for 'bestimmt' is 'special, certain'. But 'particular' seems to match better

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a wrong assumption (that "bestimmt" means "special")

Comment: @tofro  In certain (!) situations, both *besonderer* abd *bestimmter* can be translated as *special*. So what's the problem?

Comment: I want to see the examples on difference.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I'd like to see an authoritative source where *bestimmt* should be translated to "special". The most common translation is "particular", or "certain", maybe even "specific", but not "special".

Comment: @tofro thanks for the help. I've added the source, but if it's wrong, let me know, please. Anyway, I also want examples as Christian Geiselmann told

Comment: @tofro But Eleonora's question is not really about how to *translate* those words into English. She rather wants to use them correctly (with special respect to the tiny difference between them) and is asking for examples. I do not find this illegitimate. Whether she errs with the side-topic of translation (which probably was caused by a bad textbook) is irrelevant.

Comment: Auch dict.leo.org schlägt sowohl certain, als auch special vor. Als Nichtmuttersprachler (EN) ist das auch das, was ich erwartet hätte. "Mit einem bestimmten Salz kann ich meine Kaffeemaschine entkalken." - "With a certain salt ..." oder "With a special salt ..." - wieso nicht?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These examples may help you to get a feeling for the tiny difference between *bestimmter* and *besonderer*:

> Er trinkt gerne Wein, aber nur bestimmten.

Meaning: he likes drinking wine, but only a certain type (sort / year / from a certain producer)

> Er trinkt gerne Wein, aber nur besonderen.

Meaning: he likes drinking wine, but he wants the wine to be something special, something unusual; on the other hand, he is not fixated on one specific sort of wine (as in *bestimmter Wein*).

Similar:

> An bestimmten Tagen gehe ich essen.

I am used to eating out on certain days. This might be every Tuesday and Thursday. Or every 12th of a month, or whatever.

> An besonderen Tagen gehe ich essen.

I am used to eating out on special days / days that are not average days but provide some specific reason for doing something extraordinary, e.g. a birthday or so.

Note: selecting from these two words is not a question of "correct or wrong". It is a question of "what do I want to express".